# C# Console application, safest way to get the correct path to file in args

Tags: c#

I have a console application that is in the environment path that can be run from anywhere. If a user types

```
Program filename
```

From the directory where the file exits

```
File.Exists(args[0])
```

Will tell me the file exists.
But when passing args[0] it is only the file name, so I am going to assume that C# prepends:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Because the application can be run from anywhere, and the command line can have a great deal of possible input from relative paths to absolute paths I am wondering what is the safest way to get the proper directory where the file exists.

The following seems to work just fine, but am wonderig if I am missing something, is thier a better way.

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[0]);
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dir))
dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Path.GetFullPath(args[0])` - that will resolve the file name into it's full name for you.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Eddie if he solved it for you then mark it as the answer.